# Docker API version with Docker login in CentOS 7

Tags: docker, centos, ansible, docker-api

I have a problem when I launch a Ansible role for to install Docker in a CentOS 7 VM.

When the `docker-login` task runs I have the following error:

> "msg": "Docker API Error: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.22)"

And this is the Ansible role:

```
-   name: Install python setup tools
yum: name=python-setuptools
tags: docker

-   name: Install Pypi
easy_install: name=pip
tags: docker

-   name: Install docker-py
pip: name=docker-py
tags: docker

-   name: Install Docker
yum: name=docker state=latest
tags: docker

-   name: Make sure Docker is running
service: name=docker state=running
tags: docker

-   include: setup.yml

-   name: login to private Docker remote registry and force reauthentification
docker_login:
  registry: "{{ item.insecure_registry }}"
  username: "{{ item.registry_user }}"
  password: "{{ item.registry_password }}"
  reauth: yes
with_items:
  - "{{private_docker_registry}}"
when: private_docker_registry is defined
```

This installs docker 1.10.3 version with API version 1.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `api_version` argument to the `docker-login` module:

```
- name: login to private Docker remote registry and force reauthentification
  docker_login:
    registry: "{{ item.insecure_registry }}"
    username: "{{ item.registry_user }}"
    password: "{{ item.registry_password }}"
    reauth: yes
    api_version: 1.22
  with_items:
    - "{{private_docker_registry}}"
  when: private_docker_registry is defined
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have the next error: {"msg": "unsupported parameter for module: api_version"}

Comment: It is definitely [supported](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_login_module.html). If you are using an older version of Ansible, either try `docker_api_version` alias, or check a [previous revision of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9031f2a2-3210-4d9d-9d7f-38a061319382/view-source) if it works for you.